# Django start new project error

Tags: django

i have installed Python2.6 and Django1.2.4 on windows vista. or so i think django is installed.
i test it this by opening the python shell(command prompt from the python folder) and typed this:

```
import django 
django.get_version()
```

The result was "1.2.4". From this i understand that firstly python works, and second that django is installed, recognized.

Following the tutorial from Django website i get stuck on the first thing: creating a project

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

I wrote this in a new command prompt window, chdir my way to a folder i decided it'll keep the project and then wrote the line above. The error is this:

```
E:\Workspace>django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

'django-admin.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I tried with writting "python" before the line but no.
I added in the Environmental Variables , in the PATH, the path to the bin folder of django and the path to python. I have the django-admin.py file in the Python/Scripts folder.
I understand this is a very easy , newbie mistake, but it currently blocks me. If somebody has gone through this error or knows about it, a bit of help would be much appreciated.

Thank you either way!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you to add the Python/Scripts to the PATH environmental variable? You'll need to restart any command prompts you have opened for the PATH change to take effect.

Comment: I added the path to scripts and restarted the cmd and it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The same happened with me also and it is resolved by adding PATH environmental variable of Python\scripts.