# I can't launch a django project after I installed it

Tags: python, django, web, command-line

I've installed django, I've set Python (and python scripts) as part of my path, but when I type django-admin.py startproject mysite in the command line I get an error message "django-admin.py is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file".

Also what's interesting is that if I type 'import django' on the python shell it doesn't give me an error, from this it would seem that it did install properly.

I followed this tutorial to install django = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obJr6zH0C2Q&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDcTDEowl-b5nQlaDaD82r_s&index=1

what am I doing wrong? Maybe someone can do a teamviewer with me to help me out? I'm using windows 7 if that matters. thanks

Comment: This is a windows thing. There are other questions on Stackoverflow that are very similar. Have you tried to read through the solutions that appear in the 'related' column?

Comment: For instance, have you tried something like this?
`python C:\python27\scripts\django-admin.py startproject mysite`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django start new project error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846356/django-start-new-project-error)

Comment: @CyanogenCX his issue was that he didn't add Python to his path. My issue is different, I already did add Python (and python scripts) to my path.

Comment: @dave I haven't ever used django, but are you sure you don't have to say "python django-admin.py startproject mysite"

Comment: Sure looks like you didn't. Can you post your `PATH`? Have you double-checked it? Also check that `django-admin.py` does indeed exist in `C:\python27\scripts\`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was that in newer versions of django you aren't supposed to add ".py" (to the end of  django-admin)